# Presentation about generated benefit at the end of my contract

Tags: internship, presentations

I am working as a working student at a company and I start my obligatory intership next semester at the same company but in a different position.
Today my manager approached me and asked that I should write down all the projects I worked at and he also said that I have to make a half hour presentation in my last week about everything that I did and how the company benefited from me.

The problem is that I have no clue how to approach this presentation because I don't want to sound arrogant while presenting.

Also I have a hard time understanding why this presentation is even necessary, since I stop working in this position anyway.

Are these presentations normal?

I work at a technology company and at the moment I mostly write software to automate processes.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with singing your own praises, why not just come at it from the angle of "here's some work I did that was interesting and why I think it was useful." The fact that they want you to do this is a good thing - if you had been useless they wouldn't want to make a presentation of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these presentations normal?

It is common to have to do a "final presentation" for internships. They often provide a few benefits:

- Highlighting your work
- Giving you visibility to others in the company
- Helping align the internship with academic requirements
- Validating (or invalidating...) the value of the internship program
- Provides you public speaking experience (thanks HLGEM)

It can also be used as part of larger hiring processes for fulltime work.

Either way, what you should do is just ask your manager what the purpose is. Ultimately he will know better than a random user on the Internet :-)

> because i don't want to sound arrogant while presenting

Self promotion is somewhat frustrating but fairly important. Just talk about what you did. You don't have to lie or make things up, just give a presentation about what you did.

My recommendation to avoid this is to practice with your manager a few times. Ask their input - If the presentation is to a larger audience than just your team, you could even practice with the people you've worked with on a team.

When I have done this before, I always practiced at least once with my team or manager.

Comment: In benefits, you forgot to mention that it gives the intern public speaking experience which is useful from a career perspective.  And to the OP, self promotion is critical to career success, you need to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Very normal. Management want to extol your virtues and demonstrate how the internship program adds value to the company.

Don't be afraid of clearly stating benefits you have brought to the company; this will not come across as arrogant.

> i have a hard time understanding why this presentation is even necessary, since i stop working in this position anyway

You leaving is in fact one of the reasons the presentation has value. By showing what you've done it invites other team members to ask follow-up questions and capture any knowledge-transfer that may have been missed.